# Grails/ Spring security Access Denied

Tags: grails, spring-security

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.decide(AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager.java:43)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:62)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Getting this error while trying to view different pages on the website. 
Whenever after logging in I try to visit one of the pages I get this error in the log window in IntelliJ Idea ultimate. I am using secured annotation.

```
2015-12-28 09:48:54,527 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG    intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /list.html; Attributes: [_DENY_]
2015-12-28 09:48:54,527 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@fec5dc2f: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2eb76: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: B3587266591A115997973363DF758EB8; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN
2015-12-28 09:48:54,527 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN] one can reach [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN] in zero or more steps.
2015-12-28 09:48:54,557 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
Message: Access is denied
    Line | Method
->>   43 | decide    in    grails.plugin.springsecurity.access.vote.AuthenticatedVetoableDecisionManager
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     53 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|     62 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
2015-12-28 09:48:54,559 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - Executing URL mapping filter...
2015-12-28 09:48:54,649 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG filter.UrlMappingsFilter  - Matched URI [/login/denied] to URL mapping [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?], forwarding to [/grails/login/denied.dispatch] with response [class org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper]
2015-12-28 09:48:54,649 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed.
```

Can anyone please tell me what I can look at to check for the issue. I have tried to change the config.groovy files, URLmapping.groovy files.

Here is my config.groovy

```
grails.app.context='/'

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName =   'com.dtech.security.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.dtech.security.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.dtech.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl='/?login_error=1'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl='/' //send to index page for login
//redirect to Dynics home page on logout
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl='http://www.google.com'
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.useForward=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        '/'               : ['permitAll'],
        '/index'          : ['permitAll'],
        '/index.gsp'      : ['permitAll'],
        '/assets/**'      : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/js/**'       : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/css/**'      : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/images/**'   : ['permitAll'],
        '/**/favicon.ico' : ['permitAll'],
        //'/api/**'         : ['permitAll'],
        '/rmalog/**'      : ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'],
        '/api/rmalog/**'      : ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'],
```

Here is my controller with the annotation

```
package com.dtech.controllers

import com.dtech.PagedRestfulController
import com.dtech.domain.Rmalog
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication

@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER'])
class RmalogController extends PagedRestfulController {

def exportService
GrailsApplication grailsApplication

RmalogController(){
    super(Rmalog)
}

def export(){

    if(params?.formatRequest && params.formatRequest != "html"){

        if(!params.max) params.max = 15000 //set max for records export

        response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.formatRequest]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=rmalog.${params.extension}")

        def exportData = loadPagedResults(params);

        exportService.export(params.formatRequest,
                response.outputStream, exportData, [:], [:])
    }
}
}
```

Here is my viewSource for rmalog

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta name="layout" content="angular"/>
  <asset:javascript src="dynics-app/rmalog/module"/>
 </head>

 <body ng-app="dynicsApp.rmalog">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Burt Beckwith I get this error--> " Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'grails/templates/directives/crudBreadcrumbs.tpl.html' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument." Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

By default access is denied to all URLs unless there's a rule for the requested URL. Read [the docs](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/) for more info.

Your error indicates that access to `/list.html` was denied, which makes sense because nothing in the `staticRules` map covers that URL, and you didn't mention any annotation in the controller that handles that URL.

Comment: List.html is in the javascript folder, it actually goes by list.tpl.html. I have added the controller annotation to the question. What should I do to add the URL to the access properties in the Static rule mapping ?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith : when I add the /list.html to the staticURL mapping, the error goes away, but I am not able to see anything on the page, it is blank. Any suggestions??

Comment: Can you include your viewSource?

Comment: @Raz Abramov I have edited the question and added the viewSource

Comment: Is this file dynics-app/rmalog/module being fetched?

Comment: @Raz Abramov Yes It is being fetched.